# Upstart script for Celery

Tags: python, celery, upstart

I have celeryd daemons, working on small tasks. This daemon was configured with Upstart script

```
start on starting cessna
stop on stopping cessna

respawn

script
    chdir /home/ubuntu/projects/cessna
    exec su -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/projects/cessna; export MAX_POOL_SIZE="50";export newrelic-admin run-program celeryd -A cessna.celeryconfig --loglevel=info --concurrency=50 --pool=eventlet --queue=cessna_celery -E --pidfile=/tmp/cessna-3.pid >> /home/ubuntu/logs/cessna-w\
orker-3.log 2>> /home/ubuntu/errs/cessna-worker-3.log';
end script
```

Not so long I saw a lot of unack tasks in rabbitmq, no crashes in log files etc. We moved to native /etc/init.d/celeryd daemon, it solved the problem.
So, how it could be - Is there any relation between starting Celery with Upstart, and unacknowled tasks in Celery?